# Paper/Idea to get the most attractive chapter in a novel

Tags: machine-learning, classification, nlp

I face a problem as below:

1. There is a novel app and need to find the most attractive chapter in previous 30 chapters of each novel
2. So that we can limit a user continue unless he make payment

I didn't find such paper/idea through google .

What I thought is :

Set different payment point in different chapter, show to random user and record the CTR .
Then we can use it to get payment distribution to set proper payment point .
But we don't have many user now, and cost would be large .

So I wonder is there any NLP way to detect most attractive chapter ?

Comment: How do you define "attractive"? It's a very subjective concept. Do you have any data about which chapter users like the most? Otherwise what kind of predictor would you use?

Comment: @Erwan Unfortunately not . We don't have chapter rating data , how about use average word reading time of each chapter ?